# Does Azure use DPAPI And EFS under the hood?

Tags: .net, azure, security, encryption

Does Azure use DPAPI And EFS under the hood? I'm trying to compare security of competing products.

Comment: Are you asking about a particular service?

Comment: Blob and file storage. I guess sql server db too since it's a file in the system